# Plot n animated growing line plots on the same graph (matplotlib, python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, graph, line-plot

I am trying to plot multiple animated line plots on the same graph with a delay of 1 second between each line plot in matplotlib python.

My previous question:
[How to create a delay between mutiple animations on the same graph (matplotlib, python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62438829/how-to-create-a-delay-between-mutiple-animations-on-the-same-graph-matplotlib/62438968#62438968)

I have a list of lists:
[[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[2,3,5],[200,300,500]]

I want to plot each element of the list of list as animated line plot on the same graph. Animation should plot the 1st list , and then plot the second list, then the third list and then the fourth list. They shouldn't be plotted simultaneously.

Thanks

[image: Plot will look like:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of matplotlibs interactive mode as shown here:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.ion()   # set interactive mode
plt.show()
x = np.arange(130, 190, 1)
y = 97.928 * np.exp(- np.exp(-  0.1416 * (x - 146.1)))
z = 96.9684 * np.exp(- np.exp(-0.1530 * (x - 144.4)))
y_z=[y,z]
ax.set_xlim(x[0],x[-1])
ax.set_ylim(min(y[0],z[0]),max(y[-1],z[-1]))

color=['green','red']

k=0
for i in y_z:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        line, = ax.plot(x[:j],i[:j],color=color[k])
        plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
        plt.pause(0.1)
    k=k+1
```

[image]

Comment: Please check the image I have added, The plot should be animation, as in it should pass through the points

Comment: Thankyou . I am trying to have a continuous connected line plot

Comment: Happy to help. If you feel that the above solution helped resolve your issue, please check the green mark. The above edit will draw a continuous connected line plot.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the edit. I still do not get the continuous plot as the figure you have uploaded

Comment: I copy pasted the code. But I still get points of "*"

Comment: Yes, the marker was left in place. Now, you should be good.

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted the solution. If you dont mind, could you let me know how to save this gif graph

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216178/discussion-between-sameeresque-and-jerry-george).