# Animate lines with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I want to create an animation with matplotlib, with multiple lines, not linked.

I can create this by :

```
def animate(i) :
    a = []
    a.append((x1,x2))
    a.append((y1,y2))
    a.append('b')
    a.append((x3,x4))
    a.append((y3,y4))
    a.append('r')
    a.append((x5,x6))
    a.append((y5,y6))
    a.append('g')
    a = plt.plot(*a)
    return a
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 10, blit = True, interval = 50, save_count = 50, repeat = False)
```

With this code, I can't set line's linewidth.

I've tried to add plt.plot directly to a, but I have an error with zorder

What can I do ?

Thanks !

PS : I apologize for my poor English...

Edit : my code is below

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation # pour l'animation
import matplotlib.lines as lines

nombre_etapes = 0

nombre_disques = 4

etapes = []
#on crée l'état initial : tous les disques sur le bâton 0
etapes.append([[i for i in range(nombre_disques, 0, -1)], [], []])
print("état initial : ")
print(etapes)

mouvements = [None]
def hanoi(n, origine, destination, intermediaire) :
    global nombre_etapes
    #global etapes
    if n > 0 :        
        hanoi(n - 1, origine, intermediaire, destination)
        nombre_etapes += 1
        #on crée le nouvel état        
        etat_actuel = [x for x in etapes[-1]]
        #print("état actuel avant mouvement", etat_actuel)
        disque_a_bouger = etat_actuel[origine].pop()
        #print("disque qui bouge : {}".format(disque_a_bouger))
        etat_actuel[destination].append(disque_a_bouger)
        #print("état actuel après mouvement", etat_actuel)
        etapes.append(etat_actuel)
        #print("etapes : ")
        #print(etapes)
        print(str(origine) + " --> " + str(destination))
        mouvements.append([origine, destination])
        hanoi(n - 1, intermediaire, destination, origine)
        nombre_etapes += 1

#longueurs pour dessin
rayon = 10
ecart_vertical = 0.5
epaisseur_disque = 0.5
epaisseur_baton = 2

hanoi(nombre_disques,0,2,1)
#print(mouvements)

etat = [[i for i in range(nombre_disques, 0, -1)], [], []]

def dessine_batons() :
    batons = []
    for idBaton in range(3) :
        abscisse = (2 * idBaton + 1) * nombre_disques * rayon + 2 * idBaton * rayon
        ordonnee_1 = 0
        ordonnee_2 = 4 * ecart_vertical + epaisseur_disque * nombre_disques
        batons.append((abscisse, abscisse))
        batons.append((ordonnee_1, ordonnee_2))
        batons.append('b')
    #print(batons)
    batons = plt.plot(*batons)
    return batons



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
abscisse = 3 * nombre_disques * rayon + 2 * rayon
ordonnee = ecart_vertical
disques = [[]]

couleurs = ["", "red", "blue", "grey", "green", "black", "cyan", "magenta", "crimson", "pink", "orange"]
for idDisque in range(nombre_disques, 0, -1) :
    abscisses = [abscisse - idDisque * rayon, abscisse + idDisque * rayon]
    ordonnees = [ordonnee, ordonnee]
    ordonnee += ecart_vertical + epaisseur_disque
    disque, = ax.plot(abscisses, ordonnees, c = couleurs[idDisque], linewidth = 20, zorder = 1)
    disques.append(disque)




def animate_5(idEtape, disques) :
    if idEtape != 0 :         
        #on récupère le mouvement
        mouvement = mouvements[idEtape]
        origine, destination = mouvement
        disque_qui_bouge = etat[origine].pop()
        etat[destination].append(disque_qui_bouge)
    for idBaton in range(3) :
        abscisse = (2 * idBaton + 1) * nombre_disques * rayon + 2 * idBaton * rayon
        ordonnee = ecart_vertical
        for disque in etat[idBaton] :
            abscisses = [abscisse - disque * rayon, abscisse + disque * rayon]
            ordonnees = [ordonnee, ordonnee]
            disques[disque].set_data(abscisses, ordonnees)
            disques[disque].set_zorder(disque)
            ordonnee += ecart_vertical + epaisseur_disque
    plt.pause(0.1)
    return disques



plt.axis([-10, 5 * nombre_disques * rayon + 4 * rayon + nombre_disques * rayon + 5, 0, 4 * ecart_vertical + epaisseur_disque * nombre_disques + 5])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_5, init_func = dessine_batons, fargs = [disques], frames = len(mouvements), blit = False, interval = 50, save_count = 50, repeat = False) 


plt.show()
```

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only three steps to follow:

- Create some artists at the initialisation stage
- Update their coordinates in the `update` function
- Don't forget to return a list of updated artists.

> **fargs**: tuple or None, optional
>
> Additional arguments to pass to each call to *func*.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 5

x = np.linspace(0, 7.5, 100)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.sin(x+0.5)
y3 = [0] * len(x)
ys = [y1, y2, y3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

line1, = ax.plot(x, y1, label='zorder=2', zorder=2, color='orange') #bottom
line2, = ax.plot(x, y2, label='zorder=4', zorder=4, color='blue')
line3, = ax.plot(x, y3, label='zorder=3', zorder=3, color='lightgrey', linewidth=8)
lines = [line1, line2, line3]

def update(num, x, ys, lines):
    for i in range(len(ys)):
        lines[i].set_data(x[:num], ys[i][:num])

    if num > len(x)/2:
        line1.set_linewidth(10)
        line1.set_zorder(5)       #upper
        line2.set_zorder(1)       #bottom

    print(line1.get_zorder())

    return lines


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func=update, frames=len(x), fargs=[x, ys, lines],
                            blit = True, interval = 50, save_count = 50, repeat = False)

plt.show()
```

Reference:

- [two lines matplotib animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165233/two-lines-matplotib-animation)
- [Matplotlib multiple animate multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049762/matplotlib-multiple-animate-multiple-lines)

---

According to [matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation)

> If `blit == True`, *func* must return an iterable of all [artists](https://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html)
> that were modified or created. This information is used by the blitting
> algorithm to determine which parts of the figure have to be updated.
>
> The return value is unused if `blit == False` and may be omitted in
> that case.

Your `animate_5()` returns `disques` at last. You init `disques` with `[[]]`. Empty list is not *artists*. You should modify the logical to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I dit not well explain what I want.

I have several segments which extremities must be calculated at every frame. For example, a red segment goes to right, and a blue one goes down.

I tried to adapt your code, but I have the error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_zorder'

Comment: @rognntudjuu Since I don't know how you call `get_zorder`, so I just give you an example how to call it and set linewidth.

Comment: I've edited my post to add my code. It works with blit = False, but I have an error with blit = True : 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_zorder''

Comment: @rognntudjuu Could you initilize your variables properly, so that I could you where you got the error.

Comment: I've added my all code

I wanted to put this code on my Numworks, before I Checked if it supports animation... but I want to know how to do

Comment: @rognntudjuu I edited my answer to figure out where you're wrong when `blit = True`.